# Polymorphic collection in efcore 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Wondering whether it is possible to achieve the below with efcore 5

```
public class Booking
{
    public Guid Id {get;set}

    public BookingType BookingType {get;set;}

   public ICollection<BookingDetail> BookingDetails {get;set;}

}
```

BookingDetail is an abstract class
There are different types of Booking Details

```
public class PoolGroupBooking : BookingDetail
{
}
```

```
public class DriveupBooking : BookingDetail
{
}
```

I want BookingDetails collection to be populated with the object of the appropriate derived type, based on BookingType column

I would like to use TPH for storing the different attributes of BookingDetail into one BookingDetail table. However, the discriminator is in the parent table Booking

- Can i use polymorphic collections where the BookingDetails property gets filled with the appropriate concrete type based on the BookingType property
- Can i use a column from a different table as a discriminator

#### Include provider and version information

EF Core version:5.0
Database provider: (e.g. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer)
Target framework: (e.g. .NET 5.0)
Operating system:
IDE: (e.g. Visual Studio 2019 16.3)

Comment: This should be possible I have done it a few times with multiple types.  You will need to set up a discriminator in EFContext.  There should be a few examples of EF Core TPH.

Comment: The answer of your second question is no. Since the first relies on the second, the answer is also no.